# How do you get WCF serialization to preserve a non-default Comparer on a generic Dictionary?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, dictionary, iequalitycomparer

Suppose we start from scratch in Visual Studio 2010 and add a 'WCF Service Aplication'. We add this method and implementation:

```
// (in IService1.cs)
    [OperationContract]
    Dictionary<string, string> GetDictionary();

// (in Service1.svc.cs)
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetDictionary()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>(
            StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
```

Then we add a new 'Console Application' to the same solution, add a Service Reference to our service project (using all the default settings), and add this code to `Main`:

```
        var c = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

        var d = c.GetDictionary();

        d.Add("key",string.Empty);
        // Since this *should* be a case-insensitive dictionary,
        // this add *should* fail
        d.Add("KEY", string.Empty);

        Console.WriteLine("Both Add()s succeeded :(");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

We expect this code to fall over, because a case-insensitive dictionary would regard `key` and `KEY` as the same key, and so would throw on the second `Add`.

Unfortunately, when everything is compiled and run, we get a sad face `:(`, because when the `Dictionary` comes across the WCF layer it 'forgets' that it was made with a specific, non-default, `Comparer`, and instead acquires `string`s default equality comparer.

**Is there an easy setting to change so that the `Comparer` property of the `Dictionary` will be preserved as it goes across the wire? Or must I create a custom class?**

(I've seen [XML serialization of a Dictionary with a custom IEqualityComparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366541/xml-serialization-of-a-dictionary-with-a-custom-iequalitycomparer) but it didn't offer me much enlightenment. I've also seen [this codeproject comment from 3 years ago](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2555734/WCF-DataContract-Dictionary-lt-string-object-gt-Ty.aspx), but it is my question, not an answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the standard mechanism like "Add Service Reference" etc., WCF **by design** will create a completely separate **copy** of your data structures based on the ***structure*** on the wire, e.g. the XML-serialized ***structure*** that can be expressed in XML schema (XSD).

This does **not** include anything that's more *behavior* (code) rather than actual data - things like comparers etc.

There is no setting to "turn" this on - it just cannot be done. The only way to solve this - when you control both ends of the communication wire, and both are .NET platforms - is to **share** that common stuff both sides need (service contracts, data contracts etc.) in a separate assembly that both the server as well as the client reference. On the client, you need to make sure to add the reference to that shared assembly *before* creating the WCF proxy - in that case, the WCF runtime will reuse the existing data structures (like your dictionary with a custom comparer) from the shared assembly, instead of creating new, boiler-plate copies.

Comment: Perfect! I have added a bit of highlighting on the bit that made the penny drop for me :)